# SELECT AS STRUCT/VALUES

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-spanner

I am wondering what the possible use cases are for the `SELECT` [`AS STRUCT|VALUES`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_as_struct) modifier for GoogleSQL beyond the sort of textbook examples in the documentation.

The `AS STRUCT` reduces a non-scalar row into a scalar `STRUCT, so something like:

```
SELECT "David" AS name, 20 AS age
```

Could be converted into a subquery-able (scalar) item by doing something like:

```
SELECT  (
    SELECT AS STRUCT "David" AS name, 20 AS age
)
```

Or adding a bunch of debug info into a single (scalar) column by doing something like:

```
SELECT "David" AS name, 20 AS age, 
    (SELECT AS STRUCT 1 AS a, 2 AS b) debug
FROM (SELECT NULL)
```

But beyond that I can't see too much use, and I've never used it outside of trivial debugging queries myself. I was wondering if hopefully someone on the BigQuery team can explain:

- What are some actual examples when you use or find these two modifier keywords being used?
- Do any other SQL dialects use that construction (or a similar construction) and if not, why did GoogleSQL need to support it?

Answer (score 1):

In following example the struct is used to left join tbl2 to tbl1. If there are several matching entries in tbl1, take only one (`LIMIT 1`). Thus the row size of tbl1 keeps constant. The `SELECT AS STRUCT` puts all rows of tbl2 into one structure.

```
WITH
  tbl1 as (SELECT * FROM UNNEST([1,2]) AS x),
  tbl2 AS (SELECT "a" AS name, 1 AS val
  UNION ALL SELECT "b", 2
  UNION ALL SELECT "bb", 2 )

SELECT *,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE x=val LIMIT 1)
  ) AS joined_table
FROM tbl1
```

Comment: thanks for the example, but what would be the use case for doing something like that? The above seems more like a test example with the values "a", "b", "bb", etc. Where would this actually be necessary?